# How to make a Continuous Line Plot with NaN Values?

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

How can I make a line plot where NaN data is ignored so I have continuous lines? So for example, with the data below every other observation is connected.

[image]

```
cpu = DataFrame.from_dict({'{host=ny-service05}': {Timestamp('2014-10-16 14:19:36'): nan,
 Timestamp('2014-10-16 14:19:41'): 19.199999999999999,
 Timestamp('2014-10-16 14:19:51'): nan,
 Timestamp('2014-10-16 14:19:56'): 17.333333333333332,
 Timestamp('2014-10-16 14:20:06'): nan},
'{host=ny-service04}': {Timestamp('2014-10-16 14:19:36'): 13.866666666666667,
 Timestamp('2014-10-16 14:19:41'): nan,
 Timestamp('2014-10-16 14:19:51'): 12.466666666666667,
 Timestamp('2014-10-16 14:19:56'): nan,
 Timestamp('2014-10-16 14:20:06'): 18.399999999999999}})
```

Comment: There are only going to be two columns and the `nan`s are interleaved? In that case, `cpu.fillna(method='pad')[::2].plot()` will suffice.

Comment: @CTZhu: No, looking for a generic solution where the dataframe is N columns, and the nans can be anywhere

Comment: But how are you going to 'align' the data? Say, if the `nan`s are not interleaved by a fixed step? Since your data appears to a time series, maybe downsample it to every minute (or other)? Of course if the alignment is not an issue, @farenorth 's solution will work.

Comment: Yup, I don't care about alignment in this case

Answer (score 3):

How about using `interpolate()`:

```
cpu.interpolate().plot()
```

Answer (score 1):

If every other data is NaN, you could slice it using one of:

```
plot(time[::2], dat[::2])
plot(time[1::2], dat[1::2])
```

Or if the data is not so regular, you could create a logical array that you use to create new arrays:

```
logic_array = ~(np.isnan(dat))

plot(time[logic_array], dat[logic_array])
```

Note that this latter approach is not very efficient because it creates array *copies* rather than *views* ([check this out](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)), but that's the way this works.

Comment: Any chance of a little spoonfeeding? Not sure how to apply this to my dataframe...

Comment: You'd need to provide a more complete question for me (or anyone) to 'spoonfeed' you. i.e. provide a minimal example-code that can be executed to get to the point where you have data objects with NaN values.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: `cpu[~np.isnan(cpu['{host=ny-service04}'])].plot(marker='.')`

Comment: I think the issue is that I don't want to change the data, but rather just the plot. My guess is matplotlib just doesn't work that way. But I guess I could get the same visual look (if markers are not used) by just filling in the NaNs with the The avg of the before and after points.

Comment: The line I provided in the comment doesn't change the data. It produces a copy that gets plotted.

Comment: Is sets every value of  the second column (ny-service05) to NaN

Comment: Code added - sorry for not doing that in the first place.